# Oracle exporting custom tables with data, triggers, sequences into dmp file

Tags: oracle, export

topic says all, i need to export custom tables with data, triggers and sequences into dmp file.

```
exp SYSTEM/password FULL=y FILE=dba.dmp LOG=dba.log CONSISTENT=y
```

This example helps to export all database, but i need to export custom objects. 
Maybe someone can tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you identify what a "custom table" is?  Perhaps you're trying to export all the objects in a particular schema?

Comment: @Justin_Cave custom tables = few tables by my choice from list of tables(schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a parameter file which specifies the tables that you want to include.

Here is an example:

```
DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR
FILESIZE=2G
EXCLUDE=INDEX
EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT
EXCLUDE=GRANT,ROLE_GRANT,DEFAULT_ROLE
EXCLUDE=VIEW,PACKAGE,PROCEDURE,FUNCTION
EXCLUDE=COMMENT,JOB,SYNONYM
EXCLUDE=TABLE:" NOT IN ('table1','table2','table3')"
```

Then run the expdb utility, specifying your parameter file path:

```
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/expdp user/pass@db SCHEMAS=schemaname DUMPFILE=$DMPFILE LOGFILE=$DMPLOG PARFILE=$DATA_PUMP_PAR
```

That will export table1, table2 and table3 with associated sequences, data and triggers.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and mark as answer if it will help.

Comment: I mark it as correct answer, as my final update script was based on this. So thank you idea for your help.